# How to disable HTTP in artifactory

Tags: http, ssl, artifactory

We have a requirement to use HTTPS and disable HTTP, currently we are using Artifactory OSS version 4.0.0 so redirecting http requests using reverse proxy is not feasible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Naresh.G

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options to achieve this:

1. Use an http reverse proxy such as [NginX](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+NGINX) or [Apache httpd](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Apache) in front of Artifactory. This can be done with any version of Artifactory including the OSS. Versions 4.3.1 and above includes a [functionality](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy) which helps generating the reverse proxy configuration (please notice it does not configure the proxy but rather provide the required configuration).
2. Configure the Artifactory Tomcat with SSL/TLS support. The Tomcat [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) explains how to do that.

One thing to take into consideration is that you will get better performance using the first option